# c++ std::nextbefore function?

Tags: c++, precision

There exists [`std::nextafter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) function however no `nextbefore`. Naively I would do

```
double a = 1.0;
double b = 2.0;

std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
std::cout << std::nextafter(a,b) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::nextafter(a,2*a-b) << std::endl;
```

to get

```
1.0000000000000002
0.99999999999999989
```

But using `2a-b` seems sketchy in the general case. Is there a more robust way to achieve nextbefore. ie: the next floating point number from *a* in the opposite direction from *a* to *b*?

Demo https://godbolt.org/z/sKsK49oa3

Comment: Why you used `2*a-b` at all (ignoring general case)?

Comment: If you are not interested in expanding both sides of the intervall [a,b], you may want to state what to do when `a == b`.

Comment: 2*a-b is the value on the other side of a the same distance away. It's the first thing that came to mind. Adam Kotwasinski's answer is a better solution.

Comment: Adams answers is ok, but it has a branch which hurts performance, to provide better solution context is needed.

Comment: Note that C23 introduces nextdown and nextup

Answer (score 5):

It's a kludge, but what about:

```
std::nextafter(a, (b > a) ? 
    -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() : 
    std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ``infinity``. The standard has this to say ``Only meaningful if std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity == true`` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity

Comment: @bradgonesurfing That's easily checked at compile time, so that you could use `lowest` and `max` instead.

Comment: A perfect solution would produce `b` when `b == a`, as `std::nextafter(a,b)` does.